# Reassign labels of columns from 0 after drop of few columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I removed some duplicate columns by the following command.

```
columns = XY.columns[:-1].tolist()
XY1 = XY.drop_duplicates(subset=columns,keep='first').
```

The result is below:

> ```
> Combined Series shape :  (100, 4)                            
> Combined Series:     1    222  223          0                
> 0    0    0    0  1998.850000                                
> 1    0    0    0     0.947361
> 2    0    0    0     0.947361
> 3    0    0    0     0.947361
> 4    0    0    0     0.947361
> ```
>
> Now the columns is labelled 1 222 223 0 (0 label at the end is because of concat with another df !!)  I want the columns to be
>   re-labelled from index 0 onwards. How'll I do it?

Comment: What is `print (XY.head().to_dict())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first create a dictionary with the mapping you want

```
trafo_dict = {x:y for x,y in zip( [1,222,223,0],np.linspace(0,3,4))}
```

Then you need to rename columns. This can be done with pd.DataFrame.rename:

```
  XY1 = XY1.rename(columns=trafo_dict)
```

Edit: If you want it in a more general fashion use:

```
np.linspace(0,XY1.shape[1]-1,XY1.shape[1])
```

Comment: It worked. But it adds 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 ... 
How'll i make it integer?

Comment: use trafo_dict = {x:int(y) ... } to do so

Comment: If I concat two df's on columns, is there an easy way to reset column Ids? With the above  method also, if the original label is appearing twice in two columns, it does not solve the issue:
 trafo_dict = {x:y for x,y in zip( list(XY.columns.values),np.linspace(0,XY.shape[1]-1,XY.shape[1]))}
    XY.rename(columns=trafo_dict, inplace=True)
    print(XY.columns.values)
[181.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, .....174.0, 175.0, 176.0, 177.0, 178.0, 179.0, 180.0, 181.0]

Originally the label was 0 for column 0 and last one.

Comment: A dirty but quick fix should be: Edit the column names before you concatinate, e.g. 1,2,3, for df1 and 1_,2_,3_ etc. for df2. Concatination results in df3 and use the procedure I suggested for df3